# Windows azure free subscibe

Tags: windows, azure

One month ago I was created Free Windows Azure sybscriptions and one windows Azure site. Now, when free subscriptions ended, I create new subscriptions. But i can't get access to my old web site, which use old subsctiptions. And i haven't backup of my old website. Can I change subscribtion on it, or get access to my datas?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to renew the old subscription. For retrieve your data changing your old subscription in pay per use and you can get acces to your data. It's very low cost if you want juste recovered your data

Comment: But how can i do this. I can't see any methods too pay, on my old subscribe page/

Comment: Have you tried submitting a Windows Azure support ticket?  Depending on how long ago the previous subscription expired, they MAY be able to help.

Comment: You can transform your free account to pay per use in your subscription page. Normally you have an option "Add a subscription"